# Running functions on list retrieved from tkinter text widget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-text

I am having trouble applying my functions to the list I retrieve from my tkinter text widget. The list is retrieved via a button `command=lambda: get_list())`. I am trying to apply `def func_1():` however it doesn't throw an error, it just runs it immediately before I've even entered any data.

```
dictionary = {
    'A': '1',
    'B': '2',
    'C': '3'}

def get_list():
    text_input = text.get("1.0", "end-1c").split("\n")
    return text_input


def func_1(text_input):
    x=0
    while x < len(text_input):
        text_replace = (text_input[x]).replace(',', '')
        text_split = text_replace.split()
        not_found = True
        for key in dictionary:
            if key in text_split:
                result = dictionary[key]
                return (result)
                not_found = False
                break
        if not_found :
            return ("Some Error Message")
        x = x + 1
print(func_1(get_list()))
```

If I input a few lines;

```
 1. A, D, E
 2. B 
 3. C
```

It skips `func_1`, and states the if not found text:

```
Some Error Message
```

I need it to `get` the text widget input, split into a list at `"\n"`, and run `func_1` on as many items as were lines input into the widget.

func_1 should take each list item, replace any commas, and then split it into it's own list for the for loop.

I'm not sure how to break it down any differently than that.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @BryanOakley - I've edited OP.

Comment: _"It skips func_1, and states the if not found text: `Some Error Message`"_ - that seems impossible, since the only way for `Some Error Message` to appear is if `func_1` is not skipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need it to get the text widget input, split into a list at "\n", and run func_1 on as many items as were lines input into the widget.

If that is the case, then you need to do exactly that: run `func_1` on each line:

```
text_input = text.get("1.0", "end-1c").split("\n")
for line in text_input:
    func_1(line)
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan! I’ve been trying every way I could find outside of those functions to have it process and then insert back into a different widget that I didn’t consider a for loop in the cmd function.

Comment: Bryan, when I add this in, it gives me the following error: ```TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable``` and calls out line 65 for me ```text_replace = (text_input[x]).replace(',', '')```

Comment: Ignore my last comment - I realized that I was trying to .replace/split a list. With that being said, several of my functions that I will need to run on the individual lines will need to be formatted slightly to extract data correctly. How would I be able to manipulate the lines to be able to replace and split them with a comma?

Comment: To answer my latest question, I just adjusted ```func_1``` to address ```line``` instead of the ```text_input``` and it works! Thanks for pointing me in the direction I needed, Bryan!

Comment: Bryan, how would I then insert this back into a separate text widget by line or display in a label by line? I've tried the .insert route however it just inserts it all as 1 line and changes to 2nd line when the character count for the 1st line maxes out.